# Redirect codeignitor easyappointments /index.php to /index.php/backend page?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url, redirect

I am doing a project in *easyappointments* platform. My codebase is under "src" folder. I would like to redirect *`/src/index.php`* to *`/src/index.php/backend`*

Your suggestion highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if backend is a controller then better way is to change the default controller in routes (application/config/routes.php) to backend

```
 $route['default_controller'] = "backend";
```